# awk command to run a C++ code and input several times

Tags: awk

Say, I have a C code which I compile like:

```
$ gcc code.c -o f.out
$ ./f.out inputfile outputfile
```

Then the code asks for input

```
$ enter mass:
```

Now if I need to run this code for example 200 times and the input files have name : 0c.txt, 1c.txt, ....., 199c.txt etc and I want to use same value of mass every time (e.g. mass=6) then how do I write an "awk" command for that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you hard-code the value of mass in you code itself?

Comment: Why awk? Shell will be simpler.

Comment: What makes you think `awk` is the best tool in this case?

Comment: Thanks. Now I see shell is better than awk in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify your outputfile name. I'll assume 0c.out, 1c.out, ...

I'm also assuming that the f.out program reads the mass from stdin instead of anything more complicated.

```awk
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {  
    mass = 6
    for (i=0; i<200; i++) {
        cmd = sprintf("./f.out %dc.txt %dc.out", i, i)
        print mass |& cmd
        close(cmd, "to")
        while ((cmd |& getline out) > 0) {
            do something with each line of output from ./f.out
        }
        close(cmd)
    }
}
```

ref http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html

In bash, you'd write:

```bsh
for i in $(seq 0 199); do
    echo 6 | ./f.out ${i}c.txt ${i}c.out
done
```